# How to @GET method output in REST Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

The main method already can print a output, so I just think it can use @GET to show the output in the web service.

I use Jersey, Because I call a shellscript in the code, the script calculates something I need, I just want @GET those output. So it is not a simple String output like "Hello, world" The code is,

```
public class ShellScript {

@Path("/")
@GET
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                  
    String[] command = { "hello.sh"};
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);                    
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(        
        process.getInputStream()));                                          
    String s;                                                                
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {                                
      System.out.println("Script output: " + s);                             
    }                                                                      
  }
}
```

When I enter the right URL, I cannot get any result.
How can I get the result of String s?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The closest you'll get to something like that can be accomplished with [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start).

It could look like this:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

But a lot more stuff is happening than just a simple main method, read up on the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, but I down vote all answers that propose a Spring solution, when the question is clearly about a JAX-RS/Jersey. Proposing someone switch to a completely different framework it hardly a solution.

Comment: I'm proposing a feasible solution to what the user wants to accomplish, I'n just trying to help. You downvoting the answer don't help anybody

Comment: Like I said, IMO switching to a completely different framework is hardly a solution for a simple case like this, and for most answer that I personally see where people post Spring answers to Jersey questions. That's why there are tags. If you are proficient in the tag, then post  the answer using that framework. It's like saying it's ok to post an answer that invloves using Flask, a Python REST framework. Where would the limit stop if we don't restrict that by tags

Comment: This is just my stance, and it's something that I stick by to try and keep the tag that I am most active in, clean. Nothing against you.

Comment: _"You downvoting the answer don't help anybody "_ The goal is to try and get users to delete their answers, as trying to point out that their answers (IMO) are clearly out of bounds. Again, in attempts to try and keep the tag clean

Comment: Like I said, you're not helping anybody...

Comment: Like I said, I am trying to keep tag clean, which _is_ helpful. But we can agree to disagree. We'll  can just leave it at that

Comment: I saw your previous answers, it looks like ServletContextListener works, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion,you want to output message to the webservice.But the Get method means get resource from web service,maybe you should use HttpServletresponse to response message to web service.